# Suppressing bugs in next SonarQube analysis

Tags: sonarqube, benchmarking

We have started using SonarQube analysis for C#, JavaScript. Our application is old one. So when we did analysis for the first time (for first release) it showed bugs in thousands.Now what we want is to set benchmark for bugs. Now when I go for next scan for the same project I should not get same thousand defects again, instead it should give only new bugs related to current release(second release). Do we have something in SonarQube to configure which sets benchmark.

Comment: Update your code and run the analysis again. The dashboard should indicate that there is an improvement.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [fixing the leak](http://docs.sonarqube.org/x/nQBb). You can configure your quality gates to rely on issues introduced during the leak period (instead of the absolute value)

Comment: Could you please specify in details.

Comment: have a look at [sonarqube.com](https://sonarqube.com/quality_gates/show/4) for an example
for most metric you now have an equivalent on new code, so the code newly added